# Question about Girsanov theorem

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-differential-equations

Tn the book "Stochastic Differential Equation" from Oksendal one can find the following theorem(6th edition, Theorem 8.6.8):

> Let $X(t)=X^x(t)$ and $Y(t)=Y^x(t)$ be an Itô diffusion and an Itô
>   process, respectively, of the forms
>
> $$\begin{align*}dX(t) &= b(X(t))dt + \sigma(X(t))dB(t) \\ dY(t) &= [\gamma(t,\omega) + b(Y(t))]dt +
>  \sigma(Y(t))dB(t), \end{align*} $$ then there exists a stochastic
>   process $M_t$ and a probability measure $Q$ $$dQ:= M_t dP$$ such that
>   the $Q$-law of $Y^x_t$ is the same as the $P$-law of $X^x_t$

**Questions**

- What is $P$ in the above theorem? Is it the probability law $P^0$ of the brownian motion starting at $0$? Or is $P$ any measure? Could I choose for $P$  the probability law of $Y_t$?
- According to the definition of a [law of a process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_%28stochastic_processes%29) the theorem claims
  $$ P(X_t^x \in A) = Q(Y_t^x \in A). $$ Later it is claimed that also
  $$ \mathbb{E}_P[f(X_t^x)] = \mathbb{E}_Q[f(Y_t^x)]$$
  holds for $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$, how does this follow?
- I have read a different version of the theorem, claiming that if $P$ denotes the path measure of $X_t$ and $Q$ the path measure of $Y_t$, then
  $$ dQ = M_t dP$$ holds. How does this fit and what is meant with path measure? Is it
  $$ Q(A):=P^0 (Y_t \in A ) \quad P(A):=P^0(X_t \in A) ? $$

Answer (score 0):

1. The two processes are defined on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$: $P$ is that probability measure.
2. Riesz representation theorem says that those two statements (either define a measure explicitly on Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or define a linear functional on $C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$) are equivalent.
3. Those two statement are also equivalent. A stochastic process, with continuous sample paths in your case, is just a probability measure on $C([0,\infty), \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Thank you. Question to 1): isn't it clear by the construction of the ito-itegral that $P$ has to be the probability law of the brownian motion starting at $0$? At least in the book SDE of Oksendal he states that $P$ always has this meaning. Question to 2): I think in the equivalent statement, it should be that $Q$ is the path measure of $X_t$ and $P$ the pathmeasure of $Y_t$ right? Is the meaning in the last statement $\Omega \simeq C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R})$ and thus the path measure of a process $X_t$ is simply $$A \mapsto \mathbb{P}(X_t \in A)?$$

Comment: 1) Ah, no. How do you get that $P$ is the law, i.e. finite dimensional distributions, of Bm...? That doesn't make sense. Oksendal probably means that "$dB_t$ is always a $P$-Bm in this book." When you change the underlying measure, you change the law. That's actually kind of the point of Girsanov.

Comment: 2) So $P$ and $Q$ are measures on that $\Omega$ you wrote down...

Comment: 1) In the 5th edition SDE from Oksendal he states on page 23 **"Here - and in the following - E means the same as $E^0$, the expectation w.r.t. the law $P^0$ for Bm starting at $0$. And $P$ means the same as $P^0$."** Then on page 26 the Ito-Integral is defined for simple functions as the sum of the Bm - thus this new constructed process exists on the probability space with measure $P^0$, right? In the mentioned Girsanov theorem he does not explicitly explain what $P$ is. On page 327 (List of Symbols) $P$ is listed as the symbol for the probability law of $B_t$ starting at $0$.

Comment: 2) I thought that would make sense, because $\Omega$ can be identified as the set of paths. Could you explain to me the definition of 'Path measure'?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up the law of a process and the underlying measure. To talk about stochastic processes, you need to fix a probability space first, correct? $P$ is the probability measure that defines this prob space. So the law of a process is defined using $P$. If you change the measure, in this case to one that's absolutely continuous with respect to $P$, you change the law, correct? A $P$-Bm is not be a $Q$-Bm in general.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18226/discussion-between-michael-and-adam).